# How can i get a proper string prior to a word containing letters and digits OR digits all together

Tags: regex

I have a string that contains a string and a sequence in the end with letters and/or numbers.

I would to match the whole text without the capital letters and/or digits, but also be able to match the whole text if they are not there at all.

How should a lookahead look in this case if i want to check if the following word consists of letters and/or digits

Text cases like this:

"Green Ambience 100AG2"

"Green Ambience 100A2 102"

"Green Ambience 1003"

"Green Ambience AFDF12"

or

"Green Ambience" (My current only matches "Green" in this case, but i would want the whole string if we dont have garbage in the end)

Desired result:
"Green Ambience"

Current regex:
(.*(?=\s))

Hopefully someone can help teach me how the lookaheads can check for letters and digits in a mix (or digits alone) - currently just checking for the last space, but that wont work if its end of line or if we in theory get "Green Ambience 10A01 102" where i still only want "Green Ambience"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to match up to the point where alphanumeric strings containing at least one digit or ALLCAPS words at the end of the string start appearing.

Thus, you may use this for matching:

```js
^(.*?)(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]*\d.*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oVc0n4/5). You can use the following if you can use the regex replace method:

```js
\s+[a-zA-Z]*\d.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oVc0n4/6).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]*\d.*)?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `[a-zA-Z]*\d`  - an alphanumeric string containing at least one digit
  - `.*` -  the rest of the string
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: It works great, however i can see issues if i get "Green Ambience 1002A NEWWORD"
Then i would get a match on the whole thing again

Comment: @SteffenMandrup Updated both approaches.

Comment: Sorry to be annoying, but now it wont match if its uppercase (i know my example was like that) but what if its "Green Ambience 1002A NewWord".

Comment: @SteffenMandrup So, let me guess: you want `Green Ambience` from `Green Ambience 1002A aaa`?

Comment: In genereal i want the Proper text that comes before 100A, 1001 and the likes. What comes after should be ignored

Comment: Try `^(.*?)(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]*\d.*)?$`

Comment: A small follow-up question - how could i make it stop before a special character?

Ie. "Green Ambience - A1003A 1023 new Words HERE"
Result still being "Green Ambience"

Comment: @SteffenMandrup You need something like `^(.*?)(?:\W+[a-zA-Z]*\d.*)?$` then. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oVc0n4/7).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex:

`(/([A-Za-z\s]*)?(\w?\s?)*/)[1]`

This regex will match only the string without sequences of letters and/or numbers.